# Multiple records returned that don't match a field value

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a field  `ref varchar(255)` in my table.

I have a # of inter and intra tables that use this for various queries. These have been failing mysteriously and today as a test I ran;

```
Select ref from Table1 where ref=6455186837893226538 group by ref
```

and it returned

ref

- 6455186837893226533
- 6455186837893226534
- 6455186837893226535
- 6455186837893226536
- 6455186837893226537
- 6455186837893226538

Clearly only 1 is correct. I'm unsure what to even try to debug here. Does it look like table damage? I do notice it seems to be selecting only the first 17 digits but not sure of the relevance of that.

Comment: Does it work if you surround the number with single quotes, like `where ref = '6455186837893226538'`?

Comment: @GMB Yes in fact it does

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code compares a string to a number, which might produce unexpected values when the number is too big (MySQL does floating point number comparison in this case). It is also rather inefficient, since it incurs converting the string to a number, which defeats an existing index.

You would need to perform string-wise comparison instead, by surrounding the number with single quotes:

```
select ref from Table1 where ref = '6455186837893226538' group by ref
```

Note that the purpose of your query is rather unclear; you are filtering, grouping and selecting on the same column, which does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: In terms of the group I was just trying to return representative values as (currently) the values were not unique. Really was just looking into the main table to see what/if the issue was.

Comment: What happens then if I select between tables e.g. T1.ref=T2.ref? does that somehow perform string-wise comparison?

Comment: @user3649739 They will be compared according to the type of the column, which is varchar.

Answer (score 1):

[As @GMB points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566247/multiple-records-returned-that-dont-match-a-field-value#comment110645365_62566247), you're comparing an integer to a string. It should be this.

```
select ref
from Table1
where ref='6455186837893226538'
group by ref
```

But why are you getting the results you are? Some experimentation...

```
insert into refs values
('64551868378932265'),
('645518683789322653'),
('6455186837893226539'),
('64551868378932265391'),
('6455186837893226531'),
('6455186837893226512'),
('6455186837893226123'),
('6455186837893221234');

select ref
from refs
where ref=6455186837893226539;

6455186837893226539
6455186837893226531
6455186837893226512
6455186837893226123
```

The cut off is at 6455186837893226. MySQL has to cast either `ref` or 6455186837893226. Probably something is being truncated in the casting, MySQL loves to silently truncate.

```
select cast(6455186837893226539 as char);
6455186837893226539
```

No. How about casting the string to an integer? 6455186837893226539 is very close to the limit of a 64 bit integer.

```
select cast('6455186837893226539' as signed);
6455186837893226539

select cast('6455186837893226539' as unsigned);
6455186837893226539
```

No.

This is MySQL. What's the dumbest way you could cast this? A [floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems)?

```
select cast('6455186837893226533' as float);
6.45519e18

select cast('6455186837893226539' as double);
6.455186837893226e18
```

There's 6455186837893226.

MySQL decided that the best thing to do when comparing a varchar to an integer is to cast both sides as doubles. :facepalm: